# Problem in finding android app in AT&T and Sprint android devices from the Android Market?

Tags: android

I am new to android development, i created some applications and published in android market place. I am facing issues with some devices like AT&T and Sprint android devices that these devices are unable to find my application in android market.

Can any one tell me why these devices are not able to find my app from the android market?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Sathish.

Answer (score 1):

What do your apps do?

You should read and understand [Market filtering](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html).

In a nutshell, it seems likely that those devices that cannot see your apps are either unable to run your app (so they never see it), or the carrier has modified the firmware image or market experience to prevent installation of some types of app.